# How to install php5.6-xdebug in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, vim, php, ubuntu-16.04, xdebug

I try to install vdebug in ubuntu 16.04. I am running php5.6. When I do `sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug`. Error is:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-xdebug : Depends: phpapi-20121212 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I do `sudo apt-get install php-xdebug`, it is installed, but does it mean php-xdebug is equivalent for php7-xdebug, php 7 only. Is it a way to install php5.6-xdebug explicitly.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/856996/cant-install-xdebug-depends-phpapi-20121212-ubuntu-14-04

It looks like the same problem with solution

Comment: I followed it. When I press F5 in vim, it seems vdebug is not working. Is it a way to know that apt-get install php5.6 php-xdebug, that php means php5.6?

Comment: They were using an old version with php 5.5 support. Have you checked also the ppa option ?